# Como leer el valor de un archivo (pdf, word, etc.) enviado hacia una aplicación PHP

Tags: php, formularios, phpmailer

Estoy intentado enviar mails con datos adjuntos mediante phpMailer desde Angular. En Angular tengo un formulario mediante el cual se envían los datos a un back en php extremadamente simple, donde solo tengo el phpmailer y unas variables para capturar y leer los datos del formulario mediante 'php://input'. El echo es que por lo que leí no sirve para enctype="multipart/form-data" que es precisamente lo que intento hacer.
Si retiro toda la lógica y el input para enviar datos adjuntos del formulario y del back todo funciona perfectamente ósea envía el email sin problemas. El echo es que cuando lo agrego deja de funcionar y me devuelve un error que comparto mas abajo.
El error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Comparto el código PHP donde se recibe la info para después enviarla:

```
<?php
require_once('cors.php');
  ?> 

<?php
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
    $email = $data['email'];
    $asunto = $data['asunto'];
    $cuerpoEmail = $data['cuerpoEmail'];
    $cv = $data['cv'];             

$body = "email: " . $email . " asunto: " . $asunto . "cuerpoEmail: " . $cuerpoEmail;

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require 'PHPMailer/Exception.php';
require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailer.php';
require 'PHPMailer/SMTP.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

try {
  //Server settings
  //$mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;                      //Enable verbose debug output
    $mail->isSMTP();                                            //Send using SMTP
    $mail->Host       = 'smtp.gmail.com';                     //Set the SMTP server to send through
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   //Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username   = 'proveedorsmtp@gmail.com';                     //SMTP username
    $mail->Password   = 'password';                               //SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS;            //Enable implicit TLS encryption
    $mail->Port       = 465;                                    //TCP port to connect to; use 587 if you have set `SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS`

  //Recipients
  //$mail->setFrom('proveedorsmtp@gmail.com', $email);
    $mail->setFrom($email, $email);
    //$mail->addAddress('pufytos@gmail.com', 'Joe User');     //Add a recipient
    $mail->addAddress('prueba@outlook.es');               //Name is optional
  /*$mail->addReplyTo('info@example.com', 'Information');
    $mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
    $mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com'); */

    //Attachments
  //  $mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');           //Add attachments 
      $mail->addAttachment($cv['tmp_name'], $cv['name']);
   // $mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    //Optional name

    //Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  //Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = $asunto;
    $mail->Body    = $body;
    $mail->Charset = 'UTF-8';    
    //$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

    $mail->send();
    echo '<script>
    alert ("El mensaje se ha enviado correctamente");
    window.history.go(-1);
    </script>
    ';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
}
```

De esta manera envió los datos mediante el servicio de Angular. El consolo.log muestra que todos los datos son correctos al momento del envio:

```
  postUpload(upload: Upload) {
    console.log(upload)
    return this.http.post(`${this.apiUrl}/upload.php`, upload);    
  }
```

¿Alguna idea de como podre leer los datos que llegan del formulario?

Este es el resultado si agrego un "print_r($data); " despues de: "$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ta mal escrito tu variable se llama `$data =json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true); ` y tienes  `$cv = $datas['cv'];`

Comment: Hay edite la pregunta y corregí el error pero me devuelve el mismo error.

Comment: Buenas. Podrias hacer un "print_r($data); "  luego de la linea : "$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);". Y mostrarnos lo que aparece?

Comment: Edite la pregunta con el resultado del print_r, de todas maneras también lo dejo por acá: Array ( [id] => 0 [email] => adriancasanova_@outlook.es [asunto] => asd [cuerpoEmail] => asd [cv] => C:\fakepath\Captura de pantalla (1).png )

Comment: Ok, bora si queres lo del print_r, el error sigue siendo el mismo? Por que veo que en la linea  47, estas haciendo: `$cv['tmp_name'], $cv['name']` Cuando $cv es un string.

Comment: Alguna idea de como podría corregirlo?

Comment: intentalo asi: `$cv = $_FILES['cv']` y eso es todo saludos! adicional recuerda colocarle a tu form el `enctype="multipart/form-data"`